# Virtuemart 2.6.6 Return to same page after add to cart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, joomla, virtuemart

I am using joola2.5 and virtuemart 2.6.6. I have the modal pop up box enabled which pops up when I perform an add to cart operation (where I have embedded add to cart buttons in the category view).

The problem is that after adding the item the next page that is loaded is the last category that I browsed to. I would like to be able to return to the exact same page before clicking add to cart. Not sure if this is a bug, but would there be a simple variable that is stored and called to remember the last page? I guess I can just add this in the code near the add to cart button but I have no idea what it would look like or how it would be implemented.

Comment: Something is missing in your description. After pressing the "add to cart button" and the modal is displaying what do you press and the page goes to the previous page?

Comment: my apologies sir! I press continue shoppping and then it does not return to the place where i was last. You can see the behviour on localbutler.co.uk where if you add an item from the homepage in featured products it will take you back to a different place.

Comment: The problem is only to your frontpage, inner pages work just fine. Please try to check the module for "Featured Products" and set the virtuemart default page id.

Comment: It appears that way but if you goto cereals under under food cupboard > breakfast you notice that there is a banner at the top. Now if you add an item the banner disappears because it has returned to the category view and not the original menu. You can see this in the address bar. Thanks in advance. It has been baffling me for a while.

Comment: Please check what may be wrong with your menu configuration and itemid is missing.

Comment: hi Emmanuel,many thanks for your help. However when I check virtuemart module for featured products there is no field for default page ID - I goto Modules > Select module displayed on front page. Also the cereals menu has an id of 817 so not quite sure what to do here either.

Comment: Hi Emmanuel, I managed to fix the first issue by playing around with the SEF settings in joomla. Still trying to figure out why the frontpage does not return tho...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clearing your cache after activating SEF. Make sure you remove all cookies. It works on my machine, but slider is missing off front page. Good luck.

Comment: Wow - after trying the sef suggestion I didn't even think of that. Thank you!!!!!